# numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: replace

[image]Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code please?
I am trying to replace long names with short abbreviated names by using replace.
Please see picture attached.
I used the same method previously in my other set of codes. It worked fine.
I cannot understand why this is not working. Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please show how you defined df because it doesn't seem to be a dataframe.

Comment: Is df a pandas dataframe or a numpy array? It appears that you may have imported numpy as df accidentally

Comment: df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\cornwalll\Downloads\SI up to 2023 08 31.xlsx')

Comment: Please update your question with your full code so we can properly assist with the problem

Answer (score 0):

To map your dictionary as a replace across your dataframe you can do

```
df1 = df.map(dfreporters)
```

To map is over a specific column you can do

```
df1 = df['reporter'].map(dfreporters)
```

Whichever your use case requires.

Comment: I managed to get it sorted now: df1 = df.replace(to_replace={"Isle of Wight NHS Trust":"IOW", "Kent" :"K"})